# pytest no module named common

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, tox

I'm trying to get started with python and pytest, I have the following project structure :

```
.
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── my_script.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_my_script.py
```

When I run tests (using `pytest`), I get an error:

```
no module named 'common'.
```

I have also the following all configs files:

- tox.ini
- setup.py
- setup.cfg
- pyproject.toml

someone know what I missed?

 **EDIT**
here is how I import utils from test_my_script.py :

```
from common.util import func1,func2
```

Comment: Could you please share code of `test_my_script.py` module. I suggest that you have something like `from common import ...`. In this case you should try to change it to `from my_module.common import ...`

Comment: Please review @pL3b 's comment, looks like it might be helpful considering the updates from your recent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`common.util` module is not accessible from your test execution because it is located in `my_module` package.
You should use import starting from working directory which is your project root.

Consider using following import instead:

```
from my_module.common.util import func1, func2
```